# È usuale questo uso figurato del vocabolo "distonia"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Leggendo le notizie in Euronews Express ho trovato questa frase nella quale ha attirato la mia attenzione il vocabolo "distonia" (il corsivo è mio):

> La *distonia* fra Pechino e le autorità locali è però clamorosa.

Ho cercato "distonia" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato soltanto significati medici, non ho visto nessuna accezione di senso figurato. Resta chiaro però che questa frase fa un uso figurato del termine "distonia" per significare che il governo di Pechino e le autorità locali non vanno d'accordo. La mia domanda sarebbe: è usuale questo uso figurato del vocabolo "distonia"?

Comment: La risposta è molto semplice: assolutamente no. Penso che sia inteso come contrario di _sintonia_.

Comment: È invece corretto l'uso figurato di contrario di sintonia:
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sintonia_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Molto probabilmente si è pensato di impiegarlo liberamente come contrario di "sintonia", oppure interpretando (forse, ipotizzo) "-tonia" come "tono", colore, e quindi volere intendere "diversità/errata relazione/non stare bene insieme" di due colori, toni. Come due colori che non stanno bene insieme e "stonano", anche Pechino e le autorità locali hanno "stonia" (invento ora cercando di capire cosa ha portato all'errore), distonia.

"Distonia" è però un termine esclusivamente medico ed indica un *disordine del movimento*. Sicuramente non è corretto usarlo, anche se ciò che si voleva comunicare è chiaro.

Aggiungo alla risposta alcuni link ai primi risultati che ho trovato online:

- http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/distonia/
- http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/distonia.shtml
- http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/D/distonia.php
- http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/d/distonia.aspx?query=distonia

Comment: A parte che l'OP menziona il fatto di aver già consultato alcuni dizionari, è sempre apprezzabile quando la risposta è un po' ragionata, anziché consistere in un monosillabo e vari link.

Comment: Capisco cosa intendi, anche se di ragionamenti quando la risposta è così scontata se ne possono fare poco. Amplio.

Comment: Grazie, Davide.